# How do i know what is my region ID on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Try to add the firebase domain, I know whats my projectID tho not sure whats my region id, how do I find out?
ex) add domain-> PROJECT_ID. REGION_ID.r.appspot.com

Answer (score 3):

Regions are independent geographic areas that consist of compute zones.

To list all regions and zone from a project access run the following commands from cloud shell:

`gcloud compute regions list`

`gcloud compute zones list`

To set a compute region:
`gcloud config set compute/zone <region>`

To set a compute zone:
`gcloud config set compute/region <zone>`